# Can install new PyPi module with pip, but can't import it myself?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

So I'm trying to add a new script I wrote, `fakesky`, to PyPi as a module. I uploaded it to PyPi, and pip will let me install it successfully, but every time I try to import it, I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fakesky'`

The structure of the upload is as follows:

```
fakesky ->
  setup.py
  setup.cfg
  README.txt
  LICENSE
  src ->
    __init__.py (empty file)
    fakesky.py
    results_BB.txt (necessary file that fakesky.py reads)
```

And the relevant files are as follows:

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='fakesky',
    version='1.0.2',
    license='CC0 1.0',
    author="Drew Weisserman",
    author_email='drewweis@umich.edu',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    url='https://github.com/drewweis/fakesky',
    keywords='sky image',
    install_requires=[
        'matplotlib',
        'numpy',
        'pandas',
        'scipy',
        'astropy'
      ],

)
```

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
description-file=README.md
license_files=LICENSE.rst
```

I performed the following commends to upload it:

```
[cd to inside fakesky folder]
python3 setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory structure is wrong.  Recreate like this:

```
fakesky ->
  setup.py
  setup.cfg
  README.txt
  LICENSE
  src ->
    fakesky ->
      __init__.py (empty file)
      fakesky.py
      results_BB.txt (necessary file that fakesky.py reads)
```

By the way, I recommend to name the module differently than the top-level package name, to avoid confusing imports like `from fakesky import fakesky`.

Comment: That lets me import it, but then, when I try to run the module's functions, I get an error: "AttributeError: module 'fakesky' has no attribute 'generateSkyfield'". Do I need to add this into the __init__.py or setup.py somewhere?

Comment: If your `__init__.py` is empty, then you're probably going to need to adjust your import statements to `from fakesky.fakesky import generateSkyfield`. But this goes back again to what I said about renaming the submodule differently, to avoid that weirdness.

Comment: Ah, I see! What do I need to rename? The .py file or the folder it's in?

Comment: Rename the .py file.  It's nice when the package name (i.e. the folder name) matches the pip install name.

Comment: Got it, thank you! How do I change my init.py so I don't need to adjust my import statements? I'd like to be able to just do "import fakesky".

Comment: Then you have to pull names up within the `__init__.py` file.  You can do this with defining an `__all__` attribute in the submodule(s), it should be a list of the public names (as strings), and then add `from .submod import *` within the `__init__.py` file. Change "submod" to whatever you choose to rename it with.

Comment: Why is not possible just to deliver a module and we are forced to make it a package?

Comment: @adosar It is possible to deliver just a single .py module. But the package shown in this question also has package data (the .txt file), so it makes more sense for it to be a full package and not a standalone .py.

Comment: So if we have a `.py` module and some other file, e.g. `.json` files that are used from the module, it is necessary to structure it like a package?

Comment: @adosar Where will you put the `.json` files if not within a package? [With setuptools' package_data](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#package-data) at least, data files are associated with a particular package name and contained within that package directory.

Comment: @wim I was looking on this [example](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). Basically, can I add them to `src/` directly instead of adding them inside `src/example_package_YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/`?

Comment: Sure, you can add files in src, but that doesn't help you get them into your installed package. The user installing a published package doesn't see your `src/` tree at all, they see a .tar.gz or .whl file from PyPI.